# Eclipse CDT code analysis disagrees with GCC - why?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, analysis

I like to build the Android NDK example "native-audio", supplied with the NDK.
The NDK-supplied compiler swallows it without complaint, but Eclipse is showing several errors in file `native-audio-jni.c`.

In the code excerpt below, all of the static variable declarations have red underlining, because Eclipse claims that the types cannot be resolved. They are defined right up there in the `OpenSLES.h` file, which Eclipse does find if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + *left click* the file.

Note that I modified the lines where `hello_clip` and `android_clip` are included compared to the example source - I put the array declarations in those "header" files also (they contained just comma separated data), since Eclipse had a problem parsing the syntax, too:

```
static const char array[] = #include"blah.h";
```

I tried things suggested over the internet, like starting with `eclipse.exe -clean`, clean project / rebuild, refresh project, etc., none helps.

So, what could be the reason/solution for Eclipse not resolving those types?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

// for __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "YourApp", "formatted message");
// #include <android/log.h>

// for native audio
#include <SLES/OpenSLES.h>
#include <SLES/OpenSLES_Android.h>

// for native asset manager
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>

// pre-recorded sound clips, both are 8 kHz mono 16-bit signed little endian

// includes data arrays here
#include "hello_clip.h"
#include "android_clip.h"



// engine interfaces
static SLObjectItf engineObject = NULL;
static SLEngineItf engineEngine;

// output mix interfaces
static SLObjectItf outputMixObject = NULL;
static SLEnvironmentalReverbItf outputMixEnvironmentalReverb = NULL;
```

(the file is full of many more of those problems)

Comment: I resorted to disabling the relevant type of errors in the eclipse code analysis settings for the project.

Then today, after changing a few things necessary in the native-audio-jni.cpp (originally .c) file to make it compile & run with C++, I switched to workspace settings again, which have those errors enabled.
But the problems seems gone...
There is no apparent reason, no relevant seeming changes, I have no idea why, so I won't "answer your question" here, since I can't.

Comment: Actually I think you were on to something when you mentioned you switched it from C to C++.  I tried just renaming native-audio-jni.c to native-audio-jni.cpp, and that immediately resolved most of the errors.  The ones left had to do with the difference in semantics for JNIEnv (in C, you pass the "self" as the first argument, whereas in C++ you don't)